# Rails, RequireJS, C3.js: c3 is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, d3.js, requirejs, c3.js

I am trying to use `c3.js` and `d3.js` in a rails app together with RequireJS. My `application.html.erb` looks as follows:

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= yield(:title) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <%= requirejs_include_tag params[:controller] %>
  </body>
</html>
```

The current controller is `instructor` and the file that gets successfully loaded, `instructor.js` looks as follows:

**instructor.js**

```
require(["jquery", "modules/d3.min", "modules/c3.min"], function($, d3, c3)
{
  console.log(d3);
  console.log(c3);
});
```

Now when running the application there is no error but `c3` is undefined. Here's the console output:

**Console**

```
Object {version: "3.4.13", ascending: function, descending: function, min: function, max:function…} // instructors.js:3
undefined  // instructors.js:4
```

So d3.js gets loaded fine but c3.js is undefined. I do not understand what's going wrong here. Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When c3 is initializing it is looking for d3 on the global scope and if it can not find it there, it attempts to resolve it with require by a named path of d3. This dependency can create a race condition if you are loading d3 and c3 at the same time using require.

**c3.js**

```
function ChartInternal(api) {
    var $$ = this;
    $$.d3 = window.d3 ? window.d3 : typeof require !== 'undefined' ? require("d3") : undefined;
    ...
}
```

If you setup your require config to set an explicit path to d3 this should resolve the issue.

**Code**

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "d3": "modules/d3.min",
        "c3": "modules/c3.min"
    }
});

require(["d3", "c3"], function (d3, c3) {
    console.log(d3);
    console.log(c3);
});
```

**Console**

```
Object {version: "3.5.6", behavior: Object, event: null, ns: Object, time: Object…}
Object {version: "0.4.10", chart: Object}
```

Comment: What if not using require.js

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me that my application was not serving static files. You can check id in the network tab of the browser developer tools: all js and css files are returning a 404 error.

To solve it I added `app.UseStaticFiles();` in the Configure method of the Startup.cs file.

Now the scripts are loaded and c3 is defined.

I hope this helps someone.